# Rest template for postForEntity with file & other properties

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I want to upload the file with Json request in rest template along with other properties. But I couldn't able to do this.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.build();
}

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void _do() throws Exception {
    HashMap<String, String> documentProperties = new HashMap<>();
    documentProperties.put("number", "123");


    MultipartFile file = Somefile;


    UploadDocumentRequest uploadDocumentRequest = new UploadDocumentRequest();
    uploadDocumentRequest.setDocumentClass("DocClass");
    uploadDocumentRequest.setDocumentProperties(documentProperties);
    uploadDocumentRequest.setFile(file);  ----???





    ResponseEntity<String> value = restTemplate.postForEntity("URL", uploadDocumentRequest, String.class);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create `HttpEntity` with header and body.

1. Set the content-type header value to *MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA*.
2. Build the request body as an instance of `LinkedMultiValueMap` class.
3. Construct an `HttpEntity` instance that wraps the header and the body object and post it using a `RestTemplate`.

A sample code is shown as follows:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("file", getFileToBeUploaded());

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(serviveUrl, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Comment: But how can add other properties? My controller is accepting only UploadDocumentRequest class.

uploadDocumentRequest.setDocumentClass("DocClass");
uploadDocumentRequest.setDocumentProperties(documentProperties);

Comment: @User You can add other properties into `HttpHeaders` such as `headers.add(headerName, headerValue)`.

Comment: But it will go as string object. Then I have to convert String object to custom object. Can send directly as custom object?

Comment: @User No! The API for `postForEntity` cannot accept self-defined object.